# How to detect if url is requesting for file in android?

Tags: android

Suppose a link "http://xzy.com/filedownload/12345" is requesting for file.

Then how to detect this it is requesting for file so i can send this link to default browser ?

I tried like this:

```
if(url.endsWith("apk")) 
{ Intent internet = new Intent(); 
internet.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
internet.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE); 
internet.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(internet); 
}
```

but its for direct URL like (xzy.com/file.apk), now with the help htaccess in php it can be used as (xzy.com/fileload/123) but the second link not working as there is no any extension of APK on that URL.

Comment: There is no way to know what the response will be until you fetch it.

Comment: no i have seen app which will ask you to choose default browser for any type of download link

Comment: Okay, but you were asking if url is requesting for a file.

Comment: yes
http://xyz.com/filedownload/12345  this link "http://xyz.com/file.apk"
are same just difference is one is not showing file location and other is with file location , so i am not able to see if this "http://xyz.com/filedownload/12345" is requesting for file or not

Comment: is there any method to check if url is file or webpage ?

Comment: Yes, fetch it and check the mime type of the response. A web page should have `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: could you tell me what is the method for finding mime file type ?

Comment: i think there is no method